# Trying to connect database to backend using Docker and I get the following error: Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND database

Tags: mysql, docker, express

I'm trying to make a Docker project containing Backend (express.js), GUI(Angular), and Database(MySQL)containers. Each container runs correctly individually, but when I try to make the connection between database and backend I get the following error.

[image: Error trying to solve]

The file composition of the project is the following.

[image: File composition]

My docker-compose file is the following.

```
version: '3.8'

services:


  gui:
    container_name: gui-container
    restart: always
    build: ./gui
    ports:
      - '4200:4200'

    environment:
      NODE_ENV: dev
      DEBUG: 'true'
    volumes:
      - ./gui:/usr/src/app/gui
      - /usr/src/app/gui/node_modules
    links:
      - backend
    command: npm run start

  backend:
    container_name: backend-container
    restart: always
    # command: sh -c "npm cache clean --force && npm start"
    build: ./backend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/usr/src/app/backend
      - /usr/src/app/backend/node_modules
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: dev
      DATABASE_HOST: database
    depends_on:
      - database
    # command: npm run debug

  database: 
    build: ./database
    container_name: database-container
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    ports: 
      - 3318:3306
```

My config file is the following.

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

function DataBaseHandler() {
    this.connection = null;
}

DataBaseHandler.prototype.createConnection = function () {

    console.log("Trying to connect to database.");
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'database',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'testingpassword',
        database: 'KuoteSuite',
        port: 3318
    });
    this.connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("error connecting " + err.stack);
            return null;
        }
        console.log("connected as id " + this.threadId);
    });
    return this.connection;
};

module.exports = DataBaseHandler;
```

I'm trying to establish the connection inside the lead.repository.js file inside backend/repositories.

```
const Lead = require('../models/lead');
const mysql = require('mysql');

var DataBaseHandler = require("../config/DataBaseHandler");
var dataBaseHandler = new DataBaseHandler();

var connection = dataBaseHandler.createConnection();


const table = 'Lead';
// Repository uses Object Models to interact with Tables from Databases
class LeadRepository{

    async getAllLeads(){
        const result = await connection.query(`SELECT * FROM ${table}`);
        console.log("Leads in repository= "+result);
        await connection.commit();
        return result;
    }

    

}


module.exports = LeadRepository;
```

Comment: You seem to have included a handful of image files in your question where you refer to error messages, code, YAML files, _etc._  Can you delete these and replace them with the actual text?  As it is I can't run this or copy parts of the code into an answer.

Comment: I uploaded the code in text.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind `docker-compose` by default uses the service name as hostname. So if you want to connect with `database` from another container in the same `docker-compose.yml` file, you have to use the service name as hostname. In your case you should change your database host to: `http://database` instead of `127.0.0.1` in your `DatabaseHandler` line `11`.

And port to `3318` on line `15`, as you declared in your `docker-compose.yml` to port the database port to `3318` instead of `3306`. Keep in mind that for porting the syntax is: `HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I changed the connection declaration as follows but it doesn't seem to work. 

`this.connection = mysql.createConnection({ 
        host: 'http://database', 
        user: 'root',
        password: 'testingpassword',
        database: 'KuoteSuite',
     port: 3318
    });`

Comment: I geuss `host` is simply `database` without the `http://`. Else you have to access the container to see with `curl` if you can `curl http://database:3318 -v` to see the if there is a connection or if there are issues with the username and password.

Comment: I tried to connect using MySQLWorkbench and I was able to do it successfully. I don't understand why it cant connect in the backend.

Comment: I was able to execute curl localhost:3318 -v, but no curl http://database:3318 -v

This is the result:
*   Trying ::1:3318...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3318 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3318
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
* Closing connection 0
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

Comment: You curled from another container? So first run `docker exec -it backend-container bash` and then I geuss you have to install curl via `apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl` and then `curl http://database:3318 -v`. Localhost will only work from your host machine.

Comment: I tried and I get this error...

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Comment: That means `bash` is not available in your docker container. Try with `sh` instead: `docker exec -it backend-container sh`

Comment: Now I get sh: apt-get: not found

Comment: Then it is an alpine version run: `apk update && apk add curl && curl http://database:3318 -v` inside the container

Comment: Ok, now I was able to execute the command. Thank you.

* Could not resolve host: database
* Closing connection 0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: database

Comment: Is the container still running? See `docker ps | grep database-container` on the host machine

Comment: yeah, it runs ok.

f0acca9e34da   kuotesuite_database   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3318->3306/tcp   database-container

Comment: I geuss you have to use another version at the top of your `docker-compose.yml`. I see you uses a custom network, this causes the services to be in another network. Remove your custom network on line 37 and line 38 in your docker-compose file and use `3.8` as version at the top of your docker-compose file. Remove all other references to this custom network, as it prevents running the services in the same network. Once you did this, do `docker-compose up --force-recreate` and try again.

Comment: I have spent more than 48 hours trying to solve this issue and I know it must be something simple. :(

I did what you just told me and still the same error.

I deleted line 37 and 38 and all instances of my-network, and the version was already 3.8.

Comment: Please update the question by removing the images and paste everything in text, so we can help you out better. Especially your Dockerfile, databasehandler.js and docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Ok, I made the changes to the question.

Comment: The error slightly changed.

Comment: Any additional help will be apreciated. :(

Comment: As the answer of David the connection string indeed is http://database:3306.

Answer (score 1):

Connections between containers ignore Compose `ports:` (if they're present at all).  In your configuration, you always need to connect to the default `port: 3306`; since it's the default port you can probably omit that configuration.

Also consider making these parameters configurable via environment variables, since they'll be different in different environments.  For instance, the connection parameters will be different running the same code against the same containerized database if the application is running in a container or in a non-container development environment, and they'll be different again if you're running in a production environment with a cloud-hosted non-container database.

```js
this.connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST || 'localhost',
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER || 'root',
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD || 'testingpassword',
    database: process.env.DATABASE_DATABASE || 'KuoteSuite',
    port: process.env.DATABASE_PORT || 3306              // not 3318
});
```

```sh
# Local development:
export MYSQL_HOST=localhost MYSQL_PORT=3318
npm run dev
```

```yaml
# Compose setup:
version: '3.8'
services:
  database:
    build: ./database
    ports:                     # ignored for inter-container connections
      - '3318:3306'
  backend:
    build: ./backend
    depends_on:
      - database
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: dev
      DATABASE_HOST: database
      DATABASE_PORT: '3306'    # default MySQL port, not remapped ports:
```